# What would happen if an astronaut took off their helmet on mars?

Tags: mars

Would lack of oxygen/suffocation or lack of pressure/blood or body fluids boiling kill her first?

Comment: It's a duplicate, Mars' atmosphere is so thin it's really the same question.

Comment: To remove the helmet, the astronaut has to depressurize his suit first. But with no pressure in his suit, he would not be able to take off his helmet anymore.