# What would happen if an astronaut walked on mars without a spacesuit i.e. wearing just earth clothes?

Tags: mars, astronauts, oxygen, pressure

Which will happen first: Would she die due to lack of oxygen/suffocation or due to lack of pressure/boiling bodily fluids?

Comment: Looks nigh-identical to https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31508/what-would-happen-if-an-astronaut-took-off-their-helmet-on-mars, and is just as much a dupe of https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/what-are-the-consequences-if-an-astronauts-helmet-gets-damaged-during-a-spacewa

Comment: I think they will die because of boil-off of the bodily fluid first because on average humans can survive about 1 to 1.5 mins without oxygen. But because of less pressure the arteries will burst and the body will stop functioning.

Comment: @Amar Unconsciousness due to no pressure happens much quicker. The Columbia astronatus were all unconscious 15 seconds after the depressurization.

Comment: The questions wording makes it sound like her earth clothes are wearing a spacesuit

Comment: @peterh, That's what I was trying to say, they will die because of low pressure than oxygen considering they just set foot on Mars.

What do you mean by "significant difference if the astronaut is male or female"? The biological things are almost same isn't it?

Comment: @Amar Nothing. The question title narrows the topic to female astronauts, this addressed I by saying that there is no practical difference.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_11

Comment: There is no significant difference if the astronaut is male or female, he/she will be unconscious in around 15 seconds and dead in some minutes.